# How to use expr with echo and $

Tags: bash, unix

```
  #!/bin/bash

  echo "Please enter a number that can divided by 5"
  read input
  ans= 'expr $input/5'

  echo "$ans"
```

So i want this code to be something like this, a user will enter a number that can divided by 5 (5,10,15,20 etc etc) and then it will echo the answer, i am not sure whats wrong with my code it keeps saying "no such file or directory " for output not sure how to fix that.

Comment: would advice to use `ans=$(($input/5))`

Comment: Most of the functionality of `expr` has been incorporated into the POSIX arithmetic expression `$((...))`. Other than regular expression matching, it is no longer necessary (and `bash` can perform regular expression matching with its `=~` operator, so you don't need `expr` at all in `bash`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the spaces were your problem...

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter a number that can divided by 5"
read input
ans=`expr $input / 5`

echo "$ans"
```

Comment: And should change `'` to `\``